# Optional manuals? Or pre-compiled in distribution?

Tags: packaging, autoconf, automake

I'm working on a personal project written in C++, and I'm using GNU Autotools as build system.

I would like to distribute my software together with manual pages, but I'm not very fond of Groff. For this reason I decided to write everything in Asciidoc and to compile it in Groff with `a2x`.

While I'm quite satisfied with the result, <strike>I noticed that installing Asciidoc might require a lot of disk space. For instance `asciidoc-base` in Debian Stretch requires 1928 MB of dependencies!</strike> (**Edit**: not even true. I forgot to [disable suggested/recommended](https://superuser.com/questions/615565/can-i-make-apt-get-always-use-no-install-recommends), but the use case is relevant anyway).

One solution would be to make it optional. To achieve this my `configure.ac` contains the following lines:

```
AC_CHECK_PROG([asciidoc], [a2x], [a2x], [false])
AM_CONDITIONAL([ASCIIDOC_AVAIL], [test x$asciidoc != xfalse])
```

…and the `man/Makefile.am` file is defined as follows:

```
if ASCIIDOC_AVAIL

man1_MANS = foo.1
man5_MANS = foo.conf.5

foo.1: foo.1.txt
    $(asciidoc) --doctype manpage --format manpage ./$<

foo.conf.5: foo.conf.5.txt
    $(asciidoc) --doctype manpage --format manpage ./$<

clean:
    rm $(man1_MANS) $(man5_MANS)

endif
```

Even though this seems to work, I'm not very happy with it. I don't like the idea of not providing a manual.

Would it be advisable to pre-compile the man pages as part of the `make dist` step? In the same way as the distribution `foo-x.y.z.tar.gz` contains the `configure` script (which is not checked in the VCS but generated by `autoreconf`), I could make `foo.1` and `foo.conf.5` pre-compiled, and distributed with the source tarball.

Provided that this is acceptable from the "best practices" standpoint, how can I achieve it? I tried to declare them as `EXTRA_DIST` (`EXTRA_DIST = man1_MANS man5_MANS`) but I didn't have much luck.

Any idea?

**EDIT**: the [Best way to add generated files to distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164189/best-way-to-add-generated-files-to-distribution) question seems to be related, even though I doubt there's a built in mechanism for my specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even though I doubt there's a built in mechanism for my specific case.

Actually, there is such a mechanism described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Man-Pages.html), about halfway down that page.  The `dist_` prefix is what you are looking for:

```
dist_man1_MANS = foo.1
dist_man5_MANS = foo.conf.5

if ASCIIDOC_AVAIL

foo.1: foo.1.txt
    $(asciidoc) --doctype manpage --format manpage ./$<

foo.conf.5: foo.conf.5.txt
    $(asciidoc) --doctype manpage --format manpage ./$<

CLEANFILES += $(dist_man1_MANS) $(dist_man5_MANS)

endif
```

Comment: How did I miss that? Thank you so much!

Comment: Note: there are some changes I did on your solution. Im explaining a couple of things I figured out in an additional answer. Still your answer deserves acceptance :)
Also heads up: `CLEANFILES` won't work with `+=`

Comment: _Also heads up: CLEANFILES won't work with +=_  Actually it does, but you have to have `CLEANFILES =` or `CLEANFILES = somefile` declared somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

OP here.

Thanks to to ldav1s's answer, I came out with a good definition for my `man/Makefile.am` file. I put it here as an answer, but the whole credit goes to ldav1s.

Here it goes:

```
dist_man1_MANS = foo.1
dist_man5_MANS = foo.conf.5

EXTRA_DIST = foo.1.txt foo.conf.5.txt

if ASCIIDOC_AVAIL
foo.1: foo.1.txt
    $(asciidoc) --doctype manpage --format manpage ./$<

foo.conf.5: foo.conf.5.txt
    $(asciidoc) --doctype manpage --format manpage ./$<
endif

CLEANFILES = $(dist_man1_MANS) $(dist_man5_MANS)
```

Some useful information about it:

- The manpages `foo.1` and `foo.conf.5` are generated during `make dist` thanks to the `dist_` prefix (as pointed out by ldav1s). The two manpages are included in the distribution tarball.
- By having the sources `foo.1.txt` and `foo.conf.5.txt` in the `EXTRA_DIST` I get those two files to be distributed as well. This is required, since the distribution tarball would include only the compiled manpages.
- Declaring `CLEANFILES` will result in `make clean` to delete the compiled manpages.

Just to get the idea, with this configuration I can run `make dist` and obtain a tarball with the following proprieties:

1. The tarball will already contain the compiled manpages together with the asciidoc sources.
2. Running `./configure && make` immediately after extracting the tarball won't compile the manpages, as they are already available.
3. Running `./configure && make clean` immediately after extracting the tarball will remove the compiled manpages (even if they were included in the distribution tarball);

I tried to verify the behaviour of the build system when `asciidoc` is installed, and when it is not installed: I get exactly what I wanted in the first place.

1. If `asciidoc` is not installed (thus `./configure` won't detect it), running `./configure && make clean && make` won't recompile the manpages
2. If `asciidoc` is installed, running `./configure && make clean && make` will recompile the manpages.